# How to add custom button to POS Receipt in Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo-10, qweb

I'm using Odoo10, I want to add a products detail table in POS Receip, and also add another Print button to print detail table only.
I have a trouble, I don't know how to add an event to my button. Here is my module, please check for me.

[image]

Qweb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="point_of_sale_template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="PosTicket">
        <t t-jquery='.pos-sale-ticket' t-operation='after'>
            <div class="pos-sale-ticket-appended" style="clear:both; text-align: left; width: 300px; background-color: white; margin: 20px; padding: 15px; font-size: 14px;padding-bottom: 30px; display: inline-block;font-family: 'Inconsolata'; border: solid 1px rgb(220,220,220); border-radius: 3px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="background: white; margin: 20px auto;">
                    <h4>Products Detail</h4>
                <div style="display: inline-block">
                    <table class='receipt-orderlines' style="width: 300px; border">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col width='50%' />
                            <col width='25%' />
                            <col width='25%' />
                        </colgroup>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>SKU</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr t-foreach="orderlines" t-as="orderline">
                            <t t-log="orderline.get_product().cost_method" />
                            <t t-log="orderline.get_product().property_cost_method" />
                            <td>
                                <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().display_name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().default_code"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().standard_price"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
    <t t-extend="ReceiptScreenWidget">
        <t t-jquery='div.receipt-screen.screen > div > div.centered-content.touch-scrollable > div.button.print' t-operation="after">
            <div class="button print-detail">
                <i class='fa fa-print'></i> Print Detail
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

JS: I just extend pos model and add standard_price field

```
odoo.define('pos_receipt_extend', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var $ = require('jquery');
    // Add cost field to product model
    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
    models.load_fields('product.product', 'standard_price');

    var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');

});
```

**manifest**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
    "name": "Pos extend Receipt",
    "summary": "pos_es_receipt",
    "version": "8.0.1.0",
    "category": "Point Of Sale",
    "website": "http://www.difusionvisual.com",
    "author": "Difusión Visual",
    "license": "AGPL-3",
    "application": False,
    "installable": True,
    "depends": [
        "base",
        "point_of_sale",
    ],
    "qweb": [
        'static/src/xml/receipt.xml'
    ],
    "data":["views/pos_es_receipt.xml"]

}
```

Please tell me how to add an action onClick on Print Detail button

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file where you define qwerb try to use first/last kind of words in `j-query` instead of this hierarchy. Might be possible jquery couldn't find that path. Make sure you have added right path.

After that in js file, you need to extend "**export_for_printing**"  method. Generally, data write in this method is return for printing.

Also in manifest file preference of arguments are like this way: 'depends' , 'data', 'qweb'. In your view don't forgot to add path of js file. After this all try to load pos session and check weather your code is successfully working or not by putting "alert".

Comment: I have tried this. but it's working in debug mode.in normal mode the field it's not printing in pos receipt.